# Is my translation of the statement into notation correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPpNL.png)

can somebody check if my answer to the question is correct or not? I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do something else

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is this:

$$\forall x\in{\Bbb Z}\;\forall y\in{\Bbb Z}\;\exists n\in{\Bbb Z} \; [x>0\Rightarrow nx>y]$$

Comment: thank you very much. Is what I'm saying incorrect ?

Comment: All-quantification should be used for $x,y$, not existential quantification, and its $x>0$ not $n>0$.